# List the production company info for the movie with highest opening weekend Gross /Budget ratio

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

ProdCos 
ProdID ProdName ProdAddress ProdCity    ST  ProdZIP ProdPhone

AND

Movies 
MovID  MovTitle  Genre  RelDate  DirLName  DirFName  Rate Budget OpWkEnd  Rtime ProdID

I need to list the production company (ProdNamd) for the movie (ProdID) with the highest opening weekend Gross/Budget ratio.

So far I have:

```
    SELECT p.ProdName, p.ProdID, m.ProdID, MAX(SELECT SUM(m.OpWkEnd / m.Budget) AS "Ratio" )
    FROM Movies m, ProdCos p
    WHERE p.ProdID = m.ProdID
    GROUP BY p.Prodname, m.ProdID, p.ProdID;
```

It returns:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Answer (score 2):

The error is about this expression in your select statement:

`MAX(SELECT SUM(m.OpWkEnd / m.Budget) AS "Ratio" )`

You're not specifying which table to SELECT from; also, the `sum` is an agrigate function, so you wouldn't need to select its `max`, since you're not grouping that particular select statement.

However, you don't need to even SELECT anything, since you're pulling data from the tables already. You can just select the sum of those two fields directly.

See this query; I've only adjusted that one Ratio column in your selection:

```
SELECT 
    p.ProdName, p.ProdID, m.ProdID, 
    (SUM(m.OpWkEnd) / SUM(m.Budget)) AS "Ratio"
FROM 
    Movies m, ProdCos p 
WHERE
    p.ProdID = m.ProdID 
GROUP BY 
    p.Prodname, m.ProdID, p.ProdID
```

Comment: As they only want the highest ratio production company I think adding an order by and a limit 1 should get the exact result required

Comment: Good call, @MarkD. OP didn't specify the database engine being used (pretty sure it's Oracle, based on the error), so I'm not sure how I should add the limit part. (Eg TSQL uses `top`, MySQL uses `limit`, Oracle uses `rownumber`, etc). @nogear, if you need further assistance with only grabbing the first movie with the highest ratio, please specify your DB engine, and I can update my answer. But you should be able to follow MarkD's advice of just ordering and limiting your selection.

Comment: @nogear Take a look at the answer by Thorsten Kettner. My answer addresses the error you got, while Thorsten's gets you to the solution that you want.

Answer (score 1):

The straight-forward way is this: find the movie(s) with the highest ratio. Then find the related production company / companies. As of Oracle 12c this is simply:

```
select *
from prodcos
where prodid in
(
  select prodid
  from movies
  order by opwkend / budget desc
  fetch first 1 row with ties
)
```

In earlier versions you can use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` to rank your movies instead:

```
select *
from prodcos
where (prodid, 1) in
(
  select prodid, rank() over (order by opwkend / budget desc) as rnk
  from movies
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use:

SELECT p.ProdName, p.ProdID, m.ProdID, (SUM(m.OpWkEnd) /SUM(m.Budget)) AS "Ratio"
     FROM Movies m, ProdCos p
     WHERE p.ProdID = m.ProdID
     AND ROWNUM=1
     GROUP BY p.ProdName, p.ProdID, m.ProdID
     ORDER BY (SUM(m.OpWkEnd) /SUM(m.Budget)) DESC;

Which returned:

PRODNAME PR PR Ratio

Atlas Entertainment 10 10 .692962893